# Configure Wordpress pages on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, dns, google-cloud-platform

I've followed instructions to link the ip address of my wordpress VM on Google Cloud Platform to my domain name. However, this is only working for the front page. If I navigate to any other page it redirects to the ip address location. For example, if I enter the wordpress login page it redirects here:

http://104.154.242.36/wp-login.php

This is again true for all newly published pages. Instead of the domain prefix I get the IP address.

How do I set the domain so it appears for all page extensions?

Thanks, Jake

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Got to Settings > General and update the wordpress address URL and site URL to your domain name. Then go to Settings > Permalinks and select the "post name" structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly replace your Site Url setting on your wp database.

Before take a snapshot your VM just in case,
Login to your instance via SSH,
Login to your mysql instance via mysql command 'mysql -u USERNAME -p'
update 'option_name' value